# Proving Non-degenerateness for Compatible observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, commutator, observables

Hi everybody I was trying to verify the following fact but I've been having some trouble.

I need to prove that if $A,B$ are two compatible observables and their eigenvalues are non-degenerate, then the matrix elements of $\langle a^{''}|B|a' \rangle$ are all diagonal.
Well my approach was the following and it turned out to be correct:
$$ \langle a^{''} |AB-BA| a' \rangle  = \langle a^{''}|AB|a' \rangle - \langle a^{''} |BA|a'\rangle  $$
Using the identity operator on the first term of the last equality:
$$\langle a^{''}|AB|a' \rangle =  \sum_{a^{'''}} \langle a^{''}|A|a^{'''}  \rangle \langle a^{'''}|B|a^{'} \rangle $$
Since I know the eigenvalues are nondegenerate, I can safely use the orthogonality condition of the eigenkets of $A$:
$$ \sum_{a^{'''}} a^{'''} \langle a^{''} |a^{'''} \rangle \langle a^{'''}|B|a' \rangle 
 =  \sum_{a^{'''}} a^{'''} \delta_{a^{''},a^{'''}} \langle a^{'''}|B|a' \rangle = a^{''} \langle a^{''}|B|a^{'} \rangle$$
Doing the same exact procedure, but on the second term of the last equality, I get instead:
$$ \langle a^{''} |BA|a^{'}\rangle  = a^{'}\langle a^{''} |B|a^{'} \rangle $$
Which leads to the correct solution provided that we assume the condition:
$$ a^{''} \ne a^{'}$$

I was asking myself if my approach was unique or whether there might be other much quicker ways of proving this: I noticed that, in Sakurai MQM, the author either skips every computation and goes straight to the result so the doubt arose naturally.
Could somebody provide an alternative proof not involving the use of the identity operator? I'd be much more than interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that if A and B are compatible that they share eigenstates. Thus, $B \vert a' \rangle = b\vert a' \rangle$. Then, we know that $\langle a'' \vert a' \rangle = \delta_{a'',a'}$, thus we can perform this by inspection.

Though this involves Kronecker delta, which I think you have denoted as the identity operator, it is much simpler.